# Piecewise affine-isometric maps of polytopal graphs into the plane

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, euclidean-geometry

There are well-known "relatively faithful" representations of the polytopal metric subgraphs $C^n\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ (with the euclidean distance, for all $n\geq 0$) of hypercubes into the plane: their canonical orthographic projections -[pictures of $n$-cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube#Graphs). In particular each such map from $C^n\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^2$ is (when choosing scales appropriately) piecewise (restricted to each edge of $C^n$) an affine isometry.

My question is: are there many other examples of such piecewise affine-isometric (one could prefer the term "linear-isometric") maps of polytopal metric graphs into lower dimensional euclidean spaces $\mathbb R^m$ ? In particular into the plane ? The maps do not have to be projections; i am actually interested in the most general piecewise affine-isometric maps possible; but if you have results when restricting to projections that will already be useful. We can also restrict the class of polytopal graphs -like imposing all edges of the same length. Of course what is important is that the metric on the image graph is induced by the ambient $\mathbb R^m$, so that for example the image of a polytopal graph with all edges of length 1 is a unit-distance subgraph of $\mathbb R^m$. Lastly the maps do not have to be injective though they are piecewise injective -the isometric view of $C^3$ is already not injective.

I imagine that there is some literature on this, serving some particular applications, but i could not find any, and i don't know much about convex and discrete geometry.

Thank you in advance.